# When I select option, radio button's value gets changed as well. I have no clue about this behavior

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add n number of address using reactive form and formArray. My first issue is, how to select only one address as a primary using radio button? Second problem is, when I select option from select-option drop-down, radio button's value gets changed as well.

I already tried changing radio button's value programmatically by adding (change) event binding.

```
export class AppComponent  {
  public userForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.userForm = this._fb.group({
      firstName: [],
      lastName: [],
      address: this._fb.array([this.addAddressGroup()])
    });
  }

  private addAddressGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._fb.group({
      street: [],
      city: [],
      state: [],
      category: ['home'],
      isPrimary: [false, [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  get addressArray(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.userForm.get('address');
  }

  addAddress(): void {
    this.addressArray.push(this.addAddressGroup());
  }

  onRadioChange(num) {
    this.addressArray.value.forEach((address, index) => {
      address.isPrimary = num === index;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<div formArrayName="address">
          <div class="address-container" *ngFor="let group of addressArray.controls; let i = index;"
            [formGroupName]="i">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>
                <h3>Address: {{i + 1}}</h3>
              </legend>

              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
                <mat-select
                  formControlName="category">
                  <mat-option  value="home">home</mat-option>
                  <mat-option  value="work">work</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
              <br>

              <mat-radio-group
                formControlName="isPrimary"
                name="isPrimary">
                <mat-radio-button
                  [value]="true"
                  class="example-radio-button"
                  (change)="onRadioChange(i)">
                  Primary
                </mat-radio-button>
              </mat-radio-group>

              <div>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="Street" formControlName="street">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <input matInput placeholder="State" formControlName="state">
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>

            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row org-desc-parent-margin">
          <button mat-raised-button (click)="addAddress()">Add more address</button>
        </div>
```

How to reproduce: 
1) Add another address
2) Select new address as Primary
3) Change value of select-option menu of first address
4) This will change radio button's value from false to true.

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for minimum reproduction of this.

Comment: I copied your code in a material module stackblitz and I am getting:

`ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).`

Which mean you need a Stackblitz

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine, just tried it. Please provide a stackblitz reproducing the issue.

Comment: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2jdmxy)

Comment: I've added StackBlitz link. How to reproduce the error:
Step 1: Click on 'Add more address' button(This will create another address block dynamically)
Step 2: Select newly created address as Primary by clicking radio button
Step 3: Change select-option(drop-down) menu from first block of address(Observe JSON User Information down under the form)

Comment: @SachinGupta I've added the StackBlitz

Comment: @ThomasCayne Please refer StackBlitz

Comment: @AJT_82 Please refer StackBlitz and Steps to reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't see any issue, my steps: Add new address, add that address as primary (value is turned `true` for address2). Change the dropdown on first address, that radio button is still `false`, and second address radio button is still `true`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @AJT_82. Could you try clicking on both radio button at least once? And then try selecting drop-down of non-primary address. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Stackblitz (though it is producing errors in the console). It's also not easy to use radio button this way because radio buttons have 2 states. I would suggest using a checkbox (and/or style it to look like a radio button if don't like the look/feel of checkbox).

Try the below:

In your component:

```
export class RadioOverviewExample {
  isPrimaryAddress: number | null = null;
...
  onRadioChange(num) {
      this.isPrimaryAddress = num;
  }
}
```

In your template:

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="isPrimary" name="isPrimary">
   <mat-checkbox
      [checked]="isPrimaryAddress === i"
      class="example-radio-button"
      (change)="onRadioChange(i); isPrimaryAddress = i">
      Primary
   </mat-checkbox >
</mat-radio-group>
```